# How to create zoom in button in gmap3

Tags: jquery-gmap3

I want to zoom in or out of Google Maps with the buttons I designed.
but I'm not do well jquery code

```
$('#zoomInButton').click(function(){
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1); //Let me know what to do with this part.
});
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635341/zooming-in-out-an-image-by-clicking-zoom-buttons-javascript

Comment: What happens when you try the code you provided. That should correctly add 1 to the current zoom.

Comment: console : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setZoom' of undefined